# error handling in a bash subshell

Tags: bash, error-handling, exit-status, subshell

I'm writing some bash code, and I'd like the script to exit if there's any error. The set -e trick works pretty well, but not with subshells. Here's a simplified example:

```
set -e

chmod a=r file.txt
x=`grep value file.txt | awk '{print $2*2}'`
echo "okay, x=$x"

chmod a= file.txt
x=`grep value file.txt | awk '{print $2*2}'`
echo "should never be printed"
```

In this example, the second grep command fails with a non-zero exit status, but the subshell executes the awk command anyway, which completes with a status of zero. So, the subshell as a whole has an exit status of zero, and the script continues.

A websearch shows several articles about the limitations of set -e, but can anyone recommend a clean workaround?

Comment: You might also include `set -o pipefail` to catch any errors inside the pipeline. This does not work with `/bin/sh` but should with most modern shells.

Comment: The backquote ` is used in the old-style command substitution. The `foo=$(command)` syntax is recommended instead. Backslash handling inside `$()` is less surprising, and `$()` is easier to nest. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: Hmm, I just tried set -o pipefail, and the "should never be printed" is still printed.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>  x=`grep value file.txt | awk '{print $2*2}'`
> ```
>
> the second grep command fails with a non-zero exit status, but the subshell executes the awk command anyway

That doesn't really have anything to do with the subshell, but due to how pipelines work. The shell starts *both* (all) commands in the pipeline concurrently, so it doesn't even know the exit status of the left hand side before the right hand command starts.

And yes, by default, the exit status of a pipeline is that of the rightmost command. In general, that's useful, since pipelines can also finish so that the rightmost command exits without reading all input, and the left command is terminated by the SIGPIPE signal when trying to write more to the now-closed pipe.

That's not an error, since you might really not care about the rest of data. Consider something like `zcat file.gz | grep -q xyz`, which only looks if `xyz` exists *somewhere* in the data, at least once.

Anyway, as they say in comments, you use `set -o pipefail` in many shells (Bash, ksh, zsh, Busybox, at least) to have the rightmost *nonzero* exit status determine the exit status of the whole pipeline.

But note that `grep` returns with a falsy status not only in case of an error, but also if it doesn't find any matching lines. If you don't want that to be considered an error, you'll have to do more work.

In this particular case, you could have `awk` do the pattern matching too, e.g. `x=$(awk '/value/ {print $2 * 2}' < file.txt)`. That should only exit with an error if the file can't be read.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know they were executed concurrently.

Comment: set -o pipefail doesn't seem to catch this error.

Comment: @jyoung, seems to work for me, `sh -c 'set -eo pipefail; x=$(cat nosuchfile | cat); echo end'` returns with an error and no output with all shells I tried (except Dash, which doesn't support `pipefail`)

Comment: Okay, not sure what was going on, that works. Thanks a lot!